# Why its not the same layout between the brower and Salesforce1 app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, event, page-layout

I would like to understand why if I create an event from an account, I don't have the same layout (event) between the browser and the salesforce1 app?

I would like to have the browser layout in the Salesforce1 app, how can I do that please?

I tried with a compact layout but the maximum number of available fields is 10.

Aurélien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"New" actions in Salesforce1 may occur in two different forms.

- The standard New button, which serves the full page layout appropriate for the record type and profile
- A Create a Record quick action, which has its own layout.

Any actions in the action bar for Account that create child records (e.g. Log a Call, New Contact, New Event) are usually quick actions. You can customize the layouts from Create > Global Actions > Actions for global actions (I'd try there first, as I suspect the action you're looking for is the out-of-box New Event action), or from Customize > Account > Buttons, Links and Actions for object-specific actions.

The New actions that appear once you drill into a related list from the Account record in Salesforce1 are usually the standard New buttons. However, the standard New Task and New Event actions don't appear on the Open Activities related list in Salesforce1, so you won't be able to use the page layout version for New Event.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me to resolve my problem.

I edited the global action for the event and I have fields I want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices are limited by several factors. One is the speed at which a user's provider can send data to their device under the best of conditions. Depending on their location and weather conditions, that speed can drop dramatically to almost zero or to where the connection is completely lost. Mobile devices are also limited in terms of the amount of data they can hold in their memory. They're similarly limited in terms of screen real estate. Some devices have VERY small screens. Not everyone uses an HD device that can display using nearly the full surface of the mobile device at HD resolution. Some may be as small as 250 x 180 pixels. Not much can be displayed in that amount of screen real estate.

Additionally, many users pay for every MB of data they download, so the more data you send to them, the higher their cell bills are each month. If their company is paying the bill and doesn't mind paying a higher one for data they may not need, then this may not be an issue. Some older devices won't even display HTML 5 pages (my blackberry I recently replaced didn't, but also wouldn't run Salesforce1, so kind of a moot point).

If you want to force a the ability to display more than 10 fields, you'll want to create a custom page with [Mixed Visual Force and HTML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_approaches_mixed.htm). You'll want to look at the following documents to fully understand what's involved: [Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/) and [Salesforce1 Mobile App Admin Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/).